# Python to search for a specific table in word document

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python.. and have done a small hands-on on the python-docx module.
I am having a requirement in which I have to read a word document which contains multiple tables and text.
Out of this document I have to select specific table to read and that selection depends on the text written in the line just above the table, and then I have to process the data of that table.

I am able to read the table data by referring the table with its index, but in this case the table index is unknown and it can be at any position in the document. The only thing by which I can identify the table is the text written in the line just above the table.

Can you please help me achieving this?

Comment: Do you have some code to show?

Comment: I am not certain how to code this requirement as I am doing this first time.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution made using BeautifulSoup and not python-docx. What I have done here is traversed through [OOXML](http://officeopenxml.com/anatomyofOOXML.php) of word(.docx) document.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import zipfile

wordoc = input('Enter your file name here or name with path: ')
text1 = 'Enter your text written above the table'
text1 = ''.join(text1.split())
document = zipfile.ZipFile(wordoc)
xml_content = document.read('word/document.xml')
document.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_content, 'xml')

for document in soup.children:
    for body in document.children:
        for tag in body.children:
            if tag.name == 'p' and (''.join(tag.text.split())) == text1:                
                table = tag.find_next_sibling('w:tbl')
                table_contents = []
                for wtc in table.findChildren('w:tc'):
                    cell_text = ''
                    for wr in wtc.findChildren('w:r'):
                        # We want to exclude striked-out text
                        if not wr.findChildren('w:strike'):
                            cell_text += wr.text
                    table_contents.append(cell_text)
                print(table_contents)
```